# Switching to i3wm from Cinnamon

Tags: linux, cinnamon, i3-window-manager

I want to change the way that windows are layed out in cinnamon but keep all of the other features like the panel icons and menu, and interface animations. I just want windows tiled and with the keyboard shortcuts to control them. How can I make this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The i3 config file allows the use of different bars
https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_configuring_i3bar

Specifically from the page:

> It is a modular approach. If you don’t need a workspace bar at all, or if you prefer a different one (dzen2, xmobar, maybe even gnome-panel?), you can just remove the i3bar configuration and start your favorite bar instead.

replace this line in your config file:

```
bar {
    i3bar_command /home/user/bin/i3bar
}
```

with:

```
bar {
    i3bar_command command_to_launch_cinnamon_panel
}
```

I'm not an expert with Cinnamon, so I don't really know if that is possible, but like with most linux things, if there's a will, there's a way.